# Will this way of using SQLParameter make my function SQL injection proof?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-injection

Here are some simple codes that search for the value in TargetColumn where SourceColumn = SourceValue.

Here are these codes:

```
        string cmdText = "select * from " + TableName + " where " + SourceColumn + " = '" + SourceValue + "'";
        SqlCommand dbCommand = new SqlCommand(cmdText, dbConnection);
        SqlParameter sqlParam = new SqlParameter("@" + SourceColumn,  SourceValue);
        dbCommand.Parameters.Add(sqlParam);
        SqlDataReader dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader();
        dbReader.Read();
        string _targetValue = dbReader[TargetColumn].ToString();
        dbReader.Close();
        dbCommand.Dispose();
        return _targetValue;
```

And my questions are:

1. I passed SourceColumn and SourceValue to SqlCommand using SqlParameter, will this make it SQL injection proof?
2. Do I need to use TargetColumn together with SqlParameter too for SQL safety purpose? (but it is for SqlDataReader)
3. If I use SqlParameter for SqlCommand, do I still need to compose a command text in a string and pass it to SqlCommand before SqlParameter is used?
4. Why do I need to add an "@" for SourceColumn? (I just followed the tutorial and added it) And why SourceValue doesn't need an "@"?

The above codes works well to return the expected value, but I'm so not sure about the above questions.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Not even close. You are creating parameters and not using them in your query. You are still just building up an unsafe string and executing it. But why of why are you selecting every column and then only returning one? This has all kinds of red flags everywhere but if you are determined to use a single method to read any table (highly unadvised) you should only select the column you need.

Comment: There is always a risk of `SQL Injection` when using string concatenation. If the user can input anything that is sent as SQL, there's a risk. Personally, I run checks on values and choose which table/stored procedure to run from there (meaning my users never have access to send SQL Injection attempts).

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, I'm using a set of codes hoping to prevent from getting SQL injection.